# Create an 'if' statement based on value from array

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to find out how ever a user has an event in it's calendar that they are not invited as guest on. The part I think I'm wrong in is this:

```
if (guestArray.indexOf(calendarId) == false) {
```

Code:

```
function myFunction() {      
    var calendarId = 'user.name@altostrat.com';
    var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId); 
    var events = calendar.getEvents(new Date('June 1, 2015 00:00:00 CST'), 
                                    new Date('June 5, 2015 23:59:59 CST'));
    for(var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        var ev = events[i];
        var guestList  = ev.getGuestList();
        var guestArray = [];

        for (var n in guestList) {
            var guestEmail = (guestList[n].getEmail());
            guestArray.push(guestEmail);
        }

    if (guestArray.indexOf(calendarId) == false) {
        Logger.log("User not on guestlist!");
        Logger.log("TITLE: "  + ev.getTitle());
        Logger.log("DATE: "   + ev.getStartTime());  
        Logger.log("GUESTS :" + guestArray);
    }
}
```

Comment: Using the Date constructor to parse strings is not a good idea.

Comment: You can just do `if (!guestArray.indexOf(claendarId))` instead of `if (guestArray.indexOf(calendarId) == false)`and `if (GetValue())` instead of `if (GetValue() == true)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.indexOf()` returns `-1` if the value is not found and returns the index if it is found.  It doesn't return `true`/`false`.

So, change this:

```
if (guestArray.indexOf(calendarId) == false) {
```

to this:

```
if (guestArray.indexOf(calendarId) === -1) {
```

Comment: personally i think its more readable with `indexOf(calendarId) < 0`